# Directive returning ng-model value as empty in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am using this below code for directive, while am using this code ng-model returning empty value in controller.

```
myApp.directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {},
      controller: [ "$scope", function($scope) {
        var panes = $scope.panes = [];

        $scope.select = function(pane) {
          angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
            pane.selected = false;
          });
          pane.selected = true;
        };

        this.addPane = function(pane) {
          if (panes.length === 0) $scope.select(pane);
          panes.push(pane);
        };
      }],
      template:
        '<div class="tabbable">' +
          '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
            '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">'+
              '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
            '</li>' +
          '</ul>' +
          '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
    };
  }).
  directive('pane', function() {
    return {
      require: '^tabs',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: { title: '@' },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
        tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
      },
      template:
        '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
    };
});
```

Under the tab am having two text fields

```
<form role="form">
    <legend>Add City</legend>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">State</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="location.state" id="input" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter state name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="">City</label>
       <input type="text" ng-model="location.city" id="input" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter city name">
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="UpdateCity()" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
</form>
```

if i try to get for `$scope.location.city` and `$scope.location.state` value in controller am getting empty value, but if i check `{{location.city}}` in view am getting value.

before using tab directive form work perfectly, after using tab directive am getting this error.

Comment: do you define `location` object just in view?

Comment: why i should define location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use tab directive, that have isolate scope, so if you not create `location` object in needed scope it would be added to local tab scope, and you can't access it in your controller.

Comment: you mean like this **$scope.location = {};**

Comment: @Nodemon, yes, like this.

Comment: @Nodemon, can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: @Nodemon, can you change this plunkr to reproduce your issue? http://plnkr.co/edit/agodOxLr69Xo5ZelNhal?p=preview